# What is "home" actually: map.root :controller => "home"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see lots of :

```
map.root :controller => "home"
```

Its I know simple, but what does home point to? A file? A controller? How/where does it gets its magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

This particular route maps "/" to the action `index` (default) of the controller "home", most likely in "app/controllers/home_controller.rb".

`map.connect "foo", :controller => "something"`, similarly, maps /foo to the `index` action of the "something" controller.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, Rails would route root requests to the 'home' controller, although you should probably specify an action just to be unambiguous... I imagine you do want the index action

Comment: Does one define a "home" controller - like "home_controller"? Is that what it means? I was wondering if it defaulted to something I was not aware of.

Comment: Yes, you'll then have a home_controller.rb right alongside your other controllers.  You make this controller the same way you'd make any other one.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen many tutorials etc that had the text "map.root :controller => “home”" without explaining this that I wondered if it had some other behind-the-scene magic I was not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

map.root :controller => "home" has two things hapenning

1 - map.root will always consider as your web sites home page

as an example if you have your home page in a controller called 'website' and in an action called 'home_page'

you can give the root as

map.root :controller => "website", :action => 'home_page'

2 - If you are directing to a controller with out giving an action, rails will default redirect to that controllers 'index' action

So in this case

map.root :controller => "home" will redirect to 'home' controllers 'index' action

hope this helps

cheers,
sameera

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation. Sometimes I need things spelled out for me in detail.

Comment: Also remember to delete the default index.html file from the public folder. If not that route just wont work at all. :)